# What determines the ability used for a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, saving-throw

I'm new to D&D. I was reading about save throws in the Player's Handbook and saw this:

> To make a saving throw, roll a d20 and add the
>   appropriate ability modifier. For example, you use your
>   Dexterity modifier for a Dexterity saving throw.

What determines what type of saving throw it is? The DM? The attack cast on the PC? Or do you add your highest ability modifier to the d20 rolled?

Comment: @Icyfire I'm a DM. No one knows how to play D&D--not even the person who invited me; I have a feeling it is going to be chaos--so I'm quickly learning how to play the game before the session.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### The effect specifies the saving throw required, but it's ultimately up to your DM.

When a saving throw is required, the effect that caused the saving throw specifies what kind of saving throw it is. For instance, the spell [Acid Splash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/acid-splash) states that (emphasis mine):

> You hurl a bubble of acid. Choose one creature within range, or choose two creatures within range that are within 5 feet of each other. *A target must succeed on at Dexterity saving throw or take 1d6 acid damage.*

So if your character was targeted by an *acid splash*, a Dexterity saving throw would be required.

Any effect described in the rulebooks which requires a saving throw always specifies the type of saving throw required... but the DM is the ultimate arbiter of the rules, and they are free to ask for a different kind of saving throw instead, or ask for saving throws due to circumstances of their own devising not explicitly described in the rules, if it makes sense to them, as described in the DMG's section about [adjudicating saving throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#SavingThrows) (DMG p.238):

> Most of the time, a saving throw comes into play when an effect - such as a spell, monster ability, or trap - calls for it, telling you what kind of saving throw is involved and providing a DC for it.
>
> Other times, a situation arises that clearly calls for a saving throw, especially when a character is subjected to a harmful effect that can't be hedged out by armor or a shield. It's up to you to decide which ability score is involved. The Saving Throws table offers suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

## The effect dictates the ability used for the save.

When you are forced to make a saving throw, it will specify an ability. For example, many spells or attacks will give you a Constitution saving throw to prevent the effects of poison, or a Dexterity saving throw to quickly dodge a fireball. The ability used is in the text of the spell or attack that is forcing the saving throw.

The DM tells you which ability to use for the saving throw. (If you are the DM, you tell the player which ability to use based either on the effect as it is written in the notes or monster stat block or based on your own judgment.)

Answer (score 4):

**It is a combination of the rules that are written for the effect the PC is saving against, and a DM call.**

For example, the **Fireball** spell says

> Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must
>   make a Dexterity saving throw. - PHB 241

So the spell that was cast defines what the saving throw is against. When it is a spell cast, the DC is determined by the caster's proficiency in the spellcasting ability for that spell.

For example, the Wizard class description says

> Intelligence is your spellcasting ability for your wizard
>   spells, since you learn your spells through dedicated
>   study and memorization. You use your Intelligence
>   whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability.
>   In addition, you use your Intelligence modifier when
>   setting the saving throw DC for a wizard spell you cast
>   and when making an attack roll with one.
>   **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier
>   **Spell attack modifier** = your proficiency bonus + your intelligence modifier

Therefore, when a Wizard casts Fireball on a PC, the PC makes a *dexterity* saving throw, against the DC set by 8 + the wizard's Int + their proficiency bonus.

For other effects, there is also a theme to their saves. For example, saves against the *poisoned* effect are generally *constitution* saves (Stinking Cloud, Ray of Sickness, Poison Spray, etc.) and are described in their effects.
Anything that doesn't have a specific description (for example an improvised trap) would be decided upon by the GM, likely following the already common themes.

So a trap that emits a burst of flame would *likely* be a *dexterity* save, as you attempt to dodge the burst.  A trap that emits a cloud of poison would *likely* cause a *constitution* save, as you attempt to withstand the effects of the poison. However, your DM might instead ask you to dodge the poison spray, so a *dexterity* save is called for.

**Or do you add your highest ability modifier to the d20 rolled?**

NO, however, sometimes it is the action that you (the player) describe your character (the PC) attempts to do that would guide the save. Again, it is up to the DM to decide how your description might work in game mechanics. If someone tries to push you over, you might choose to try and dodge them (dexterity) rather than resist them (strength). Of course, the DM can decide that you are in no position to dodge, and therefore fail a dodge attempt by default.

Comment: If you're going to go into how GMs might make the call for which ability to use when saving, I suggest referencing/quoting "Saving Throws," DMG p.238, which goes into detail on all of this.

Comment: @mattdm Yes. Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected them.